# Persistently bugging someone about updating their profile, the 'Rails way'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails application, I wanted a user to be persistently shown a warning notice to update their profile, until they do it. Specifically I want them to fill in their name ASAP, but I don't want them to do that during signup. So I wrote the following in a partial that is loaded in my application layout:

```
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.profile.name == nil %>
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    Please fill in your Profile as soon as possible. This information is important for you to use the application properly.     
    <%= link_to "Do it now", edit_profile_path(current_user) %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

However I feel like this is a really clunky way to do it. Firstly this means that every time a signed in user accesses a page, there's a database check for their profile as well. Secondly it's logic in the view.

So my question is, what would be a more 'Rails way' to do this? Somehow move the logic into the application controller? Load the result of the logic into a session variable or something so that the database doesn't need to be checked every page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model add:

```
def need_to_update_profile?
  profile.name.blank?
end
```

This will remove logic from the view. Unfortunately the problem with checking database is much harder to avoid. The good thing is that rails caches sql results, so in fact it won't make too much database calls.

Answer (score 0):

Saving it in session is still better than checking everytime in DB but the issue is you have keep your session sync everytime user changes his/her profile. Secondly, this logic should not go to model to make it DRY you can move it in helpers because the logic applies to the view and its not a business logic.

Hope this will help.